# hostel allocation system php function

Tags: php, random

I'm writing a balloting hostel allocation system.The system is suppose to assign number to  student when they enter their reg number.
reg Number--------

on submit: the system should assign a unique value from 0-300:
//this made me to use  the code below

```
$random = rand(0,299);//this assign a unique random number

if($random <= 50){
 echo " you have being allocated a room "
}else{
 echo "No  room is allocated to u"

}
```

how do i make sure that two  candidate does not receive the same random number.

Tanks alot for the help

Answer (score 2):

you can hardly reduce chance of conflict to zero if you are not using a database for persistence. if this records will be entered into a database table you should do mysql count on insert, if the entered records does not exceeds number of rooms, insert the new record else return message to user that there are no romms left. mysql auto-increase for room number column will help here

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely cannot use a database, perhaps use the time() function plus some random number.

For example:

```
$random = time() . rand(0,1000);
```

This will echo a number like "1345164397568", and the odds of two people getting the same number are 1 in 1000, and only if they visit at exactly the same second.

Answer (score 0):

```
$already_assigned_rooms = array(201,100,400);// get database to assigned room numbers array

while( in_array( ($random = mt_rand(1,300)), $already_assigned_rooms ) );

if($random){
 echo " you have being allocated a room "
}else{
 echo "No  room is allocated to u"
}
```